# JSX element type 'Button' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I created a typescript react app and installed ant design in it. Upon calling the Button Element just like in the their documentation I am getting this error. I looked up everywhere but I am not getting any solution for my problem.

this is my React Code.

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd'
import './App.css';

const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Button type='primary'>Button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I think this is ant design related. Thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: Are you following this guide here? https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

Comment: yup I was following that guide @AlexCavazos.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox to reproduce the issue?